# Check if UI Elements are yet created

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking for a possibility to check whether an Element, like an Ellipse, that i am creating in my code is already created.

```
if (Grid_myGrid.Children.Contains(myEllipse) == true)
{
    Grid_myGrid.Children.Remove(myEllipse); 
}
```

This works if I add this to my class, but i am wondering, if there is a way to do better.

```
public Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
```

Comment: Subscribe to element's loaded event

Comment: Are you creating these in code behind, or by some automation like databinding or other stuff?

Comment: Iam Creating those in my Code. Its an Ellipse that shows a point on an BitmapImage which is a child of my Grid_myGrid. I cant just use Grid_myGrid.Clear() because this would also remove the Image. At the moment i assign  this public Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse(); with no attributes and it works fine but I want to know wheater there is a way to do it like (Pseudocode:) if(myEllipse.IsCreated == true) remove(myEllipse);

Comment: If myEllipse is null that mean myEllipse is not created, it is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creation and all, do this (For Removal Only) :

```
Ellipse myEllipse = Grid_myGrid.Children.Cast<UIElement>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.getType() == typeof(Ellipse));
if (myEllipse != null)
{
    Grid_myGrid.Children.Remove(myEllipse);
}
```

Hope it helps :)